# Unable to get mpegts with klv-metadata to flow to end of pipe from udpsrc

Tags: udp, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0, mpeg2-ts, klvdata

I've been fighting with this problem for quite a while now. I have mpegts stream with klv-metadata coming from udpsrc and the bellow gstreamer command to handle it and to pass it through to rtspclientsink.

```
   gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc address=224.1.1.1 reuse=true port=50088 socket-timestamp=1 buffer-size=100000000  ! 'video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188' !
        queue max-size-time=1700000000 max-size-buffers=50 ! tsparse set-timestamps=true ! 
        tsdemux parse-private-sections=true ignore-pcr=true name=demux
        demux. ! queue max-size-time=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! decodebin use-buffering=true ! videoconvert ! videorate ! videoscale ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=5500 key-int-max=30 ! mpegtsmux name=mux
        demux. ! queue max-size-time=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! meta/x-klv ! mux. mux. ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/testpath
```

If I switch the udpsrc to a filesrc (https://samples.ffmpeg.org/MPEG2/mpegts-klv/ <-- either of the files should work), the whole pipe works just fine.

But after I switch it to udpsrc, I only get a few frames worth of klv-data after EOS, other times I keep getting "WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:demux: CONTINUITY: Mismatch packet" .

I've used below ffmpeg command to forward the rtsp back to udp

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/testpath -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts udp://224.1.1.1:50068
```

and then I have used bellow command to listen to above udp forwarding.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e udpsrc address=224.1.1.1 reuse=true port=50068 ! 'video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188' ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! h264parse ! 'video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, alignment=au' ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink demux. ! queue ! 'meta/x-klv' ! fdsink
```

And like I said the whole flow works with filesrc in the beginning, but with udpsrc it doesn't.

All help is much appreciated.
Thanks already.

Edit: My assumption is that there's lot less klv-data in the ffmpeg files than the file I'm using (which I can't share), that the fdsink pipe doesn't work with it. But managed to write the data to a file using following

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc address=224.1.1.1 port=50088 ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! meta/x-klv ! filesink location=klv_output_night.bin
```

ffprobe from the actual udp stream

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://<multicast-addr:port>':
  Duration: N/A, start: 288.961000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x722, 90k tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1[0xfc]: Data: klv (KLVA / 0x41564C4B)
Unsupported codec with id 98311 for input stream 1
```

And 10 second analyzis from the stream made with tsduck.

```
===============================================================================
|  TRANSPORT STREAM ANALYSIS REPORT                                           |
|=============================================================================|
|  Transport Stream Id: .......... 1 (0x0001)  |  Services: .............. 1  |
|  Bytes: ......................... 6,549,920  |  PID's: Total: .......... 5  |
|  TS packets: ....................... 34,840  |         Clear: .......... 5  |
|     With invalid sync: .................. 0  |         Scrambled: ...... 0  |
|     With transport error: ............... 0  |         With PCR's: ..... 1  |
|     Suspect and ignored: ................ 0  |         Unreferenced: ... 0  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Transport stream bitrate, based on ....... 188 bytes/pkt    204 bytes/pkt  |
|  User-specified: .......................... 5,185,598 b/s    5,626,926 b/s  |
|  Estimated based on PCR's: ................ 5,185,598 b/s    5,626,926 b/s  |
|  Selected reference bitrate: .............. 5,185,598 b/s    5,626,926 b/s  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Broadcast time: ................................... 10 sec (0 min 10 sec)  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Srv Id  Service Name                              Access          Bitrate  |
|  0x0001  Service01 .................................... C    5,034,525 b/s  |
|                                                                             |
|  Note 1: C=Clear, S=Scrambled                                               |
|  Note 2: Unless specified otherwise, bitrates are based on 188 bytes/pkt    |
===============================================================================

===============================================================================
|  SERVICES ANALYSIS REPORT                                                   |
|=============================================================================|
|  Global PID's                                                               |
|  TS packets: 1,015, PID's: 2 (clear: 2, scrambled: 0)                       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     PID  Usage                                     Access          Bitrate  |
|   Total  Global PID's ................................. C      151,073 b/s  |
|   Subt.  Global PSI/SI PID's (0x00-0x1F) .............. C      151,073 b/s  |
|  0x0000  PAT .......................................... C      126,514 b/s  |
|  0x0011  SDT/BAT ...................................... C       24,559 b/s  |
|=============================================================================|
|  Service: 0x0001 (1), TS: 0x0001 (1), Original Netw: 0xFF01 (65281)         |
|  Service name: Service01, provider: FFmpeg                                  |
|  Service type: 0x01 (Digital television service)                            |
|  TS packets: 33,825, PID's: 3 (clear: 3, scrambled: 0)                      |
|  PMT PID: 0x1000 (4096), PCR PID: 0x0100 (256)                              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     PID  Usage                                     Access          Bitrate  |
|   Total  Digital television service ................... C    5,034,525 b/s  |
|  0x00FC  MPEG-2 PES private data ...................... C        2,977 b/s  |
|  0x0100  AVC video (1280x722, high profile, level 4.0,  C    4,905,034 b/s  |
|  0x1000  PMT .......................................... C      126,514 b/s  |
|          (C=Clear, S=Scrambled, +=Shared)                                   |
===============================================================================

===============================================================================
|  PIDS ANALYSIS REPORT                                                       |
|=============================================================================|
|  PID: 0x0000 (0)                                                       PAT  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Global PID                Transport:                Discontinuities:       |
|  Bitrate: ... 126,514 b/s  Packets: ........... 850  Expected: ......... 0  |
|  Access: .......... Clear  Adapt.F.: ............ 0  Unexpect: ......... 0  |
|                            Duplicated: .......... 0  Sections:              |
|                                                      Unit start: ..... 850  |
|=============================================================================|
|  PID: 0x0011 (17)                                                  SDT/BAT  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Global PID                Transport:                Discontinuities:       |
|  Bitrate: .... 24,559 b/s  Packets: ........... 165  Expected: ......... 0  |
|  Access: .......... Clear  Adapt.F.: ............ 0  Unexpect: ......... 0  |
|                            Duplicated: .......... 0  Sections:              |
|                                                      Unit start: ..... 165  |
|=============================================================================|
|  PID: 0x00FC (252)                                 MPEG-2 PES private data  |
|  PES stream id: 0xFC (MPEG-7 metadata stream)                               |
|  Service: 0x0001 (1) Service01                                              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Single Service PID        Transport:                Discontinuities:       |
|  Bitrate: ..... 2,977 b/s  Packets: ............ 20  Expected: ......... 0  |
|  Access: .......... Clear  Adapt.F.: ........... 10  Unexpect: ......... 0  |
|                            Duplicated: .......... 0  PES:                   |
|                                                      Packets: ......... 10  |
|                                                      Inv.Start: ........ 0  |
|  Clock values range:                                                        |
|                            PTS: ................ 10                         |
|                            from ................. 0                         |
|                            to ................... 0                         |
|                            Leaps: ............... 0                         |
|=============================================================================|
|  PID: 0x0100 (256)                                               AVC video  |
|  PES stream id: 0xE0 (Video 0)                                              |
|  1280x722, high profile, level 4.0, 4:2:0                                   |
|  Service: 0x0001 (1) Service01                                              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Single Service PID        Transport:                Discontinuities:       |
|  Bitrate: . 4,905,034 b/s  Packets: ........ 32,955  Expected: ......... 0  |
|  Access: .......... Clear  Adapt.F.: .......... 353  Unexpect: ......... 0  |
|                            Duplicated: .......... 0  PES:                   |
|                            TSrate: .. 5,185,598 b/s  Packets: ........ 304  |
|                                                      Inv.Start: ........ 0  |
|  Clock values range:                                                        |
|  PCR: ................ 51  PTS: ............... 304                         |
|  from ....... 316,791,000  from ......... 1,052,910                         |
|  to ......... 584,766,000  to ........... 1,955,160                         |
|  Leaps: ............... 0  Leaps: ............... 0                         |
|=============================================================================|
|  PID: 0x1000 (4096)                                                    PMT  |
|  Service: 0x0001 (1) Service01                                              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  Single Service PID        Transport:                Discontinuities:       |
|  Bitrate: ... 126,514 b/s  Packets: ........... 850  Expected: ......... 0  |
|  Access: .......... Clear  Adapt.F.: ............ 0  Unexpect: ......... 0  |
|                            Duplicated: .......... 0  Sections:              |
|                                                      Unit start: ..... 850  |
===============================================================================

===============================================================================
|  TABLES & SECTIONS ANALYSIS REPORT                                          |
|=============================================================================|
|  PID: 0x0000 (0)                                                       PAT  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0x00 (0, PAT), TID ext: 0x0001 (1)                                         |
|      Repetition: ...... 12  ms  Section cnt: ...... 850                     |
|      Min repet.: ....... 1  ms  Table cnt: ........ 850                     |
|      Max repet.: ...... 12  ms  Version: ............ 0                     |
|=============================================================================|
|  PID: 0x0011 (17)                                                  SDT/BAT  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0x42 (66, SDT Actual), TID ext: 0x0001 (1)                                 |
|      Repetition: ...... 61  ms  Section cnt: ...... 165                     |
|      Min repet.: ...... 61  ms  Table cnt: ........ 165                     |
|      Max repet.: ...... 62  ms  Version: ............ 0                     |
|=============================================================================|
|  PID: 0x1000 (4096)                                                    PMT  |
|  Service: 0x0001 (1) Service01                                              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0x02 (2, PMT), TID ext: 0x0001 (1)                                         |
|      Repetition: ...... 12  ms  Section cnt: ...... 850                     |
|      Min repet.: ....... 1  ms  Table cnt: ........ 850                     |
|      Max repet.: ...... 12  ms  Version: ............ 0                     |
===============================================================================
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue.  Some perspective from me:
Note: there are 2 main formats for KLV data in MPEG-TS streams 'Asynchronous' and 'Synchronous'.  GstTsDemux (v1.16.3) does not support Synchronous.  I don't know about later versions, but don't see it when I review the current code.
Then, there are variants of Async.  Generally it works, but I have one example Async TS stream that does not.
Both of the files you link to are Asynchronous KLV.  They work fine, also if I stream them over UDP.
What is in your UDP stream?

Comment: "They work fine, also if I stream them over UDP. What is in your UDP stream? " You mean the gstreamer pipe works for you even if you're listening to an udpsrc where the file is streamed? Or that you can just stream the file over udp and get the klv-data? Sorry, got a bit of a migraine here so running bit slow :D.

Because  I can stream the file to udp just fine, but the problem comes then with handling that udp stream with gstreamer pipe I first provided.

Comment: I stream the file over UDP, then use the gstreamer pipeline to demux that udpsrc to separate video and klv files. Note: the klv data is very sparce. Day file is 3m20s with only 6 klv pkts. Night is 6m40s with only 18 klv. So, I need to set buffer-mode=2 on filesink or it would buffer all the klv and only write once I killed it.  Also, I have removed all the properties and caps you specify: `gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=$STREAM_PORT ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! 'video/x-h264' ! filesink location="video.ts" demux. ! queue ! 'meta/x-klv' ! filesink buffer-mode=2 location="klv.ts"`

Comment: I don't think the properties and caps specifications you have are bad, just not necessary.  And I did not need `tsparse`

Comment: So, I wonder:  Is the UDP stream you are trying to process the same format/structure as your test files?

Comment: I edited the original post and added a massive dump using ffprobe from the actual udpsrc and 10-second analyzis with tsduck "tsp -I ip <multicast-addr:port> -P until --seconds 10 -P analyze -O drop". Hope this is of any help, first time working with video streams, and clearly this is not the easiest of problems, so thanks for the help :).

Comment: I think this is the problem:
`PID: 0x00FC (252)  MPEG-2 PES private data
PES stream id: 0xFC`
stream_id:0xFC indicates Synchronous KLV which tsdemux does not support.  There is a very old patch out there. I don't know how difficult to apply to current tsdemux code. I also don't know how complete it is. I am working on this myself, but have very limited time for my project.

Comment: Another option is to use ffmpeg.  It seems to work on Sync KLV streams: `ffmpeg -i udp://$STREAM_IP:$STREAM_PORT -map d -codec copy -f data "klv.ts"`

Comment: Proper credit to Michael Fien: `https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/issues/642`. That is the old patch for gstreamer tsdemux Sync KLV support.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 defined formats for KLV data in MPEG-TS streams *Asynchronous* and *Synchronous*. Current gstreamer-plugins tsdemux do not support Synchronous. (I am using v1.16.3, and I believe this is still true as of v1.22)

The test *files* you post contain Asynchronous KLV.

`PID: 0x01F1 (497)  MPEG-2 PES private data | PES stream id: 0xBD`

`stream_id: 0xBD` implies Async KLV.  Both of those streams can be processed by gstreamer using `filesrc` or streamed over udp and ingested with `udpsrc`.  This pipeline works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=$STREAM_PORT ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! 'video/x-h264' ! filesink location="video.ts" demux. ! queue ! 'meta/x-klv' ! filesink buffer-mode=2 location="klv.ts"
```

The tsduck output you post for your *UDP* stream indicates Synchronous KLV.

`PID: 0x00FC (252)  MPEG-2 PES private data PES stream id: 0xFC`

`stream id: 0xFC` implies Synchronous KLV which current tsdemux does not support. There is a very old patch out there from Michael Fien to add Sync KLV to tsdemux:

`https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/issues/642`

I expect the code has evolved over time, so don't know how difficult it is to apply to current tsdemux code. I also don't know how robust it is. I am working on this myself, but have very limited time for my project.

Another option is to use ffmpeg. It seems to work on Sync KLV streams:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://$STREAM_IP:$STREAM_PORT -map 0:0 -codec copy -f data "video.ts" -map 0:1 -codec copy -f data "klv.ts"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Guess I'll need to take a look at the patch you mentioned. That ffmpeg doesn't really help, as I still need to publish it to rtsp :( . That's why I switched to gstreamer in hopes to get it to work :/

Comment: BTW, I applied that patch to v1.16.3.  There was a little manual conflict resolution.  But, after compiling, it is working for me.

Comment: Funny thing, turns out all I needed was the following pipeline "gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc address=$STREAM_IP port=$STREAM_PORT reuse=true ! tsparse ! queue ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://$RTSP_IP:RTSP_PORT/$RTSP_PATH " And that's it, forwards the mpegts stream from udp to the rtsp. Quite literally accidentally fell to it.

Comment: I misunderstood your primary goal.  Yeah, if you don't need to demux, all these problems are avoided.  :)

Comment: Yeah I kinda got railroaded to wrong direction, as initially through demuxing it was the only way I managed to get any klv to flow through to RTSP, so I thought that's the only way to do it. Also couldn't find anything that would suggest doing it any other way. Talk about learning things the hardway :D We have this saying in Finland which roughly translates to "To climb a tree ass first", which this trully was :D But heaps of thanks for your support on the matter :)